# magento programmatically saving order takes too long

Tags: ajax, magento

I am using the following code in a controller of a custom module to change the order status using `AJAX` calls and I found it runs very slowly. I did search on Google, but there is no such a topic on it.

I added the `time()` lines to test the execution time. It takes 30 - 40 seconds to finish each call. I use this same code in `Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_OrderController` so that I can change the order status in backend, but it returns very quickly and the `exetime` is equal to `0`. I don't think this is hardware performance related, as it runs on 8GB memory and 8 cores CPU. Are there any possible reasons for `Magento` to take so long to save the order? Does this call have some limits so that it works faster in back-end?

```
public function changestatusAction()
{
    if (!isset($_POST["oid"]) || !$_POST['oid']) {
        echo '{"error":1}';
        return;
    }
    if (!isset($_POST["status"]) || !$_POST['status']) {
        echo '{"error":1}';
        return;
    }
    $errstr = "";


    try{
    $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($_POST['oid']);
    $order->addStatusHistoryComment('', $_POST['status'])
                ->setIsVisibleOnFront(false)
                ->setIsCustomerNotified(false);
    $starttime = time();            
    $order->save();
    $endtime = time();   
    $exetime = $endtime - $starttime;    
    }catch(Exception $e){
            $errstr .= $e->getMessage();
    }


    if($errstr)
        echo '{"changed":0,"err":"'.$errstr.'"}';
    else echo '{"changed":1,"exetime":"'.$exetime.'"}';
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is when magento try to send email to customer. Change parameter of method setIsCustomerNotified to true or disable magento email communication. If it help you must configure your server to properly send email

Comment: Hi Maciej, thank you for your answer. We have set the server to send emails. setIsCustomerNotified to false will not send email. I also tried to change another method to change the order status by using `setStatus($status)`. The result is the same that `$order->save()` takes more than 30 seconds to finish.

Comment: Maybe you have some event on save order, fired only on frontend so execution time is different from back-end.

Comment: Hi Maciej, thank you for your help! Yes, I found the reason. The Mage/RSS module hooked two functions `StockNotify` and `NewOrder` to the event `order_after_save`. These two functions take a very long time to finish because they will scan and clean the cache on disk to refresh the RSS notification. I disabled them now the call finishes very quickly!

Comment: How did you disabled StockNotify & NewOrder??